# Loadmore ListView Or RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I'm doing loadmore for `ListView`. When I scrolled to the last item, the event is done loadmore. Everything runs fine except for one problem, which is the complete data loadmore additional adapter then I can still recognize the new adapter is made from scratch when I see listview as reloads rather be appended to `ListView` earlier.
This is my class:

```
public class StoryListMenu extends Activity{

    private String URL;
    ListView listViewStory;
    private StoryListMenuAdapter adapter;
    private List<StoryMenu> listStory;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private View progressLoadmore;
    private boolean loadMoreStatus;
    private boolean enableLoadMore;
    private int page;
    private int currentItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_story_list_menu);

        page = 0;
        loadMoreStatus = true;
        enableLoadMore = true;
        currentItem = 0;

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_story_list_menu);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressLoadmore = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.progress_row, null, false);

        URL = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");


        listViewStory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_story_list_menu);
        listViewStory.setDivider(null);
        listStory = new ArrayList<StoryMenu>();

        listViewStory.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if(loadMoreStatus && totalItemCount > 0 && firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) {
                    loadMoreStatus = false;
                    page += AppConfig.pageSize;
                    currentItem = firstVisibleItem;
                    listViewStory.addFooterView(progressLoadmore);
                    new GetStoryList().execute();
                }
            }
        });


        new GetStoryList().execute();
    }

    private class GetStoryList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ....

                listStory.add(...);   // Data is added here
            ....
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            adapter = new StoryListMenuAdapter(listStory, getApplicationContext());
            listViewStory.setAdapter(adapter);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if(listViewStory.getFooterViewsCount() > 0) {
                listViewStory.removeFooterView(progressLoadmore);
                if(enableLoadMore)
                    listViewStory.setSelection(currentItem + 1);
                else
                    listViewStory.setSelection(currentItem);
            }

            loadMoreStatus = true;
        }

    }
}
```

I also encountered similar problems with `recyclerview`.
I looked but could not find a way how to add data to the listview adapter that users do not notice the refresh of listview adapter. Does anyone have any ideas for me?

**UPDATE:
I add Item in `listStory` then `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Its Worked fine in `ListView` but not work in `RecyclerView`. In `RecyclerView' I have a method to update data in RecyclerAdapter:

```
public void addItem(int position, StoryMenu item) {
   listStory.add(position, item);
   notifyItemInserted(position);
  }
```

And then call `addItem` method after get more data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if adapter == null and them create a new one, if its not null you can execute adapter.add(items) and notifyDataSetChanged() that will refresh the ListView, ReyclerView.

Comment: how to execute `adapter.add(items)` ?  In my `StoryListMenuAdapter` I extends `BaseAdapter`. So how to add a item in adapter?

Comment: Oh I try with `RecyclerView` its not work when I `notifyDataSetChanged()` adapter of recyclerview. Its work fine in listview.

Comment: It should be working with no animation. You can also try with notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)